# Learning geb and Spock for Mobile app

Tags: android, groovy, automated-tests, spock, geb

I am new to automation and wanted to learn geb for mobile with page objects. I have knowledge of page objects in geb. I just wanted to know from where to start writing test case. I am confused at `getBrowser()` and where to set the capabilities.

Comment: I think in your GebConfig, you can do something like this: 
 driverInstance.manage().window().size(new Dimension(100,200))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to create gebConfig.groovy script and use below code there.

```
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities

driver = { // appium driver
    DesiredCapabilities capa = new DesiredCapabilities()
    capa.setCapability('deviceName', 'Android')
    capa.setCapability('platformName', 'Android');
    capa.setCapability('appPackage', 'com.example.jiteshmohite.automationsample')
    capa.setCapability('LoginActivity', 'com.example.jiteshmohite.automationsample.LoginActivity')

    String appPath = 'C:\\temp\\automation.apk'
    String  app = new File(appPath).absolutePath
    capa.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app)

    URL appiumUrl = new URL('http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub')
    println("Creating AndroidDriver to $appiumUrl with $capa")
    new AppiumDriver(appiumUrl, capa)
}

reportsDir = "build/reports/my-reports"
```

above code will be executed by geb driver it will set given specified capabilities.